# Pattern search by NOT using Regex algorithm and code in python

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching

Today I had an interview at AMD and was asked a question which I didn't know how to solve it without Regex. Here is the question:

> Find all the pattern for the word "Hello" in a text. Consider that there is only ONE char can be in between letters of hello e.g. search for all instances of "h.ello", "hell o", "he,llo", or "hel!lo".

Comment: Is the question - solve it without using regex?

Comment: do you want to extract hello from character inbetween?

Comment: Can the char be another letter?

Comment: Is a "hello" pattern allowed as a part of some other word? In other words, is your code expected to recognize "hello" in  "xxxhel.loyyy"?

Comment: @hikerjobs Yes, basically with only built-in commands. (no importing)

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed That was the question, yes. Any forms of "hello" in the text with a character (could be a space or nothing) in between.

Comment: @chrisz He actually didn't specify and I didn't ask, but for the sake of this post, let's say yes, it can be another letter, symbol, space, or nothing. That shouldn't make any huge difference.

Comment: @DyZ He actually didn't specify and I didn't ask, but for the sake of this post, let's say yes,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you also tagged this question algorithm, I'm just going to show the general approach that I would take when looking at this question, without including any language tricks from python.

1) I would want to split the string into a list of words

2) Loop through each string in the resulting list, checking if the string matches 'hello' without the character at the current index (or if it simply matches 'hello')

3) If a match is found, return it.

Here is a simple approach in python:

```
s = "h.ello hello h!ello hell.o none of these"

all = s.split()

def drop_one(s, match):
    if s == match:
        return True # WARNING: Early Return
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[:i] + s[i+1:] == match:
            return True

matches = [x for x in all if drop_one(x, "hello")]
print(matches)
```

The output of this snippet:

```
['h.ello', 'hello', 'h!ello', 'hell.o']
```

Comment: Good algorithm! Just a quick question, he actually didn't specify and I didn't ask, what if he is looking for "hello"s with a letter in between or a space in between? (as in "h ello" for example or "htello")?

Comment: You could just loop through one char at a time, and check if drop_one holds true for the next six characters, instead of splitting by spaces.  Some advice for these types of interviews.  Always ask for clarification about everything.  Many questions are designed to require this, and the interviewer is feeling out if you know what you need to know to solve the problem.

Comment: @hikerjobs He specified only one incorrect character added in his question.

Comment: Well, he said "only ONE char can be in between letters of hello" which doesn't mean that there cannot be another character before or after. Emphasis being on the "in between." Also, if you look at his answer to DyZ above, this is indeed a possible scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I've tried to make it generic. You might have to make some minor adjustments. Let me know if you don't understand any part.

```
def checkValidity(tlist):

    tmpVar = ''

    for i in range(len(tlist)):
        if tlist[i] in set("hello"):
            tmpVar += tlist[i]

    return(tmpVar == 'hello')


mStr = "he.llo hehellbo hellox hell.o hello helloxy abhell.oyz"
mWord = "hello"

mlen = len(mStr)
wordLen = len(mWord)+1

i=0

print ("given str = ", mStr)

while i<mlen:

    tmpList = []
    if mStr[i] == 'h':
        for j in range(wordLen):
            tmpList.append(mStr[i+j])

        validFlag = checkValidity(tmpList)

        if validFlag:
            print("Match starting at index: ",i, ':', mStr[i:i+wordLen])
            i += wordLen
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```